# Rotating iPad from landscape to portrait with text input focussed

Tags: mobile-safari, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation and am getting a strange bug on the iPad. The defect occurs when I start in landscape view, focus on a text input, and then rotate the device from landscape to portrait.

The viewport is set to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

When I view the DOM in web inspector, the glitch area to the right is not represented at all. I've tried to put an `overflow-x: hidden;` on the html and body elements, but still no luck. I'm not sure if it's a me issue, Zurb issue, or iPad issue. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Defect Image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS to the containing form:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

If that doesn't do it, try moving those rules to the form's parent, etc.

This fixed a similar issue I had relating to bits of form fields not being redrawn correctly. Hacky workarounds like this make me love webdev so so much!

Comment: Does not seem to be working for me :\, thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. It's a bug with iPad's (maybe all of iOS) that when the page is smaller than the window/viewport and you have the keyboard open while rotating... it doesn't know how to handle it. Haha.

Here's how I fixed mine with **jQuery**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var iPad = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("ipad");

if(iPad > -1) {
    $('body').css({'min-height':($(window).height())});
}
```

Fixed it on mine. No more weird black box or broken looking page. Let me know how it goes for you!